# How to get rid of margins. Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, background, bootstrap-5, padding, margin

I have a problem with removing the margins in bootstrap, I want to set up two graphics to show that the page is under construction - one for desktop and one for mobile.

i tried this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .full-width-img-container {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .full-width-img-container .row {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .full-width-img {
            width: 100%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            .full-width-img {
                width: 100vw;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Strona w Budowie</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid full-width-img-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="img/mala.jpg.jpg" class="img-fluid d-block d-lg-none full-width-img" alt="mala grafika">
            <img src="img/b1.jpg" class="img-fluid d-none d-lg-block full-width-img" alt="duza grafika">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

By the way, what graphic sizes should I use for desktop and what should I use for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved.
I didn't set value for .col.

```
    .full-width-img-container,
.full-width-img-container .row,
.full-width-img-container .col {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```